# Unable to find command: platform add ios

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I have a old ionic project that run in version 1.3.3. And I updated to new version 5.4.16. But, when I try build the project using "ionic platform add ios"
Its doesn't work and I receive this message:

Unable to find command: platform add ios

I look for this in doc, but nothing done.

Is there anything I can do or some other command that replaces ionic platform add ios in newer versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's: `ionic cordova platform add ios`
https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-platform